# Enable keyboard media keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have one of those fancy keyboards with the extra media keys.  For years, I more or less ignored them.  Then my work got my a MacBook, and behold, I got spoiled.  Now I want them to work when I'm using my desktop, too.  (ubuntu 10.04 using XFCE)

So, how do I do that?  I'm most interested in the play/pause button and the volume control buttons.  I know how to set them to an application, but I don't know what the command for 'turn volume up' or 'pause banshee'.

~~ edit ~~

Note: I do *not* use xubuntu.  I tried installing it, but found that adding xfce to ubuntu worked better me than xububtu did.  (This happened back in the spring, and I don't remember specifically what my issues were)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Menu -> System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts (in gnome)
For xfce I found this:

> GNOME directly queries X11 for its media keys support, so you don't need to manually configure it. However, Xfce doesn't, and you'll have to manually get the keycodes and set the symlinks. This is actually kind of simple if you know how to do it. Here's how:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XfceMultimediaKeys

Comment: I do not have a preferences menu within system.  I can get to application shortcuts via menu -> Settings -> xfce settings -> keyboard -> application shortcuts, but I don't know how to set one to adjust the volume from there.

Comment: Is there a way I can directly run the settings program you're referring to?  What's the command that is being run by the menu choices you mention?

Comment: it's called gnome-keybinding-properties

Comment: That was what I needed (especially that link you just added)  Thanks.  (I'd upvote, but I don't have the rep yet)

Answer (score 1):

I found in Settings Manager in the Startup options, in Advanced, there is two options, select Lanch Gnome Services on Startup, and almost done.

Now just log out and log in again, and ready